# Cygwin and Curl

Tags: curl, cygwin

I have Cygwin installed with curl in directory `C:\cygwin`

I am trying to run the below, but I get `No such file or directory` for `INPUT_LIST.TXT`.  I have the `INPUT_LIST.TXT` placed in the `C:\cygwin`. Where should I place the file to make the below work?

```
xargs curl -sw “%{url_effective}\t %{http_code}\t %{redirect_url}\\n” < INPUT_LIST.TXT
```

Comment: Where are you running this from? The easiest would be to place INPUT_LIST.TXT in your home directory and use `< ~/INPUT_LIST.TXT`

Comment: Or, if you want to keep it in C:\cygwin, execute `cd /` before running your command, or add a slash before INPUT_LIST.TXT.

Comment: @Andrew and McanGeest... Thank you for the reply.  I tried your suggestions and I get:-bash: /home/E4256/INPUT_LIST.TXT: No such file or directory.  My command prompt is E4256@13KLXM1 ~  what am I doing wrong.  I  used this function xargs curl -sw “%{url_effective}\t %{http_code}\t %{redirect_url}\n” < ~/INPUT_LIST.TXT     and the INPUT_LIST.TXT is placed in this directory C:\cygwin\home\E4256

Comment: please provide the output of `ls -al ~` in your bash shell.

Comment: @ Andrew $ ls -al ~
total 28
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 E4256          mkgroup    0 Aug 19 00:20 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 E4256          mkgroup    0 Aug 19 00:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 E4256          mkgroup 1494 Aug 18 15:44 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 E4256          mkgroup 6054 Aug 18 15:44 .bashrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 E4256          mkgroup 1919 Aug 18 15:44 .inputrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 E4256          mkgroup 1236 Aug 18 15:44 .profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrators mkgroup  388 Aug 19 00:21 INPUT_LIST.TXT.txt

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I can see you've managed to name your file `INPUT_LIST.TXT.txt`, not `INPUT_LIST.TXT`.

You need to do one of the following:

- Rename the file: `mv INPUT_LIST.TXT.txt INPUT_LIST.TXT`. You should then be able to run your command as you originally wrote it.
- Use the file name you've created, finishing your command with `< INPUT_LIST.TXT.txt` instead of `< INPUT_LIST.TXT`.

Comment: @user1609391: If the answer worked, remember to mark it as accepted. Just click the hollow tick-mark on the left of the answer!